# Anonymize Amazon public URL, decode using a script on Nginx

Tags: java, url, web-applications, nginx, amazon-s3

I have been wondering if its possible to anonymize public URL. When user makes a request with this anonymized public URL, let Nginx decode, fetch and serve the URL.

Example

Public URL `http://amazon.server.com/location/file.html`

Anonymized URL `https://amazon.server.com/09872340-932872389-390643289/983724.html`

Nginx decodes `09872340-932872389-390643289/983724.html` to `location/file.html`

Added image below for further clarification. Nginx has a reverse logic to decode, whereas `Remote Server` has the logic to Anonymize URL.

[image]

**Question**
All I need to know is how would Nginx decode anonymized URL? Nginx got anonymized URL request. There has to be a way to decode it.

Comment: People giving phantom down vote needs to let me know why do you feel it should be down voted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the updated question:

> Question All I need to know is how would Nginx decode anonymized URL? Nginx got anonymized URL request. There has to be a way to decode it.

Nginx would make a request to a script, e.g., either through [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) or [`fastcgi_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_pass) et al.

The script could decode the URL and provide the actual URL through a `Location` HTTP Response Header with a `302 Found` HTTP Status.

Nginx would then have the decoded URL stored in the [`$upstream_http_location`](http://nginx.org/$upstream_http_) variable.  It could subsequently be used in another `proxy_pass` et al within a named [`location @named`](http://nginx.org/r/location), to which you could redirect the processing of the original request from the user through [`error_page 302 = @named`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page).

In all, each user request would be processed twice within nginx, but it'll all be transparent to the user -- they simply receive the resource through the original URL, with all redirects being done internally within nginx.

Comment: This makes sense. And I plan to follow this. Will of course let you know how it was finally implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Define Anonymize for a URL? You can use any of the same methods as URL shortners such as http://bitly.com. But that is not truely anonymous since there is a definite mapping between the shortened URL and the target public url. If you make this per user based there is still a mapping but it is user based.

Looks like what you are suggesting is a variation on the above scheme where instead of sending the user to the target URL via a redirect you want the your server to actually fetch the content and return to the user. You need to be aware of the linked content in the public URL such as style sheets and images and adjust them accordingly. Many of the standard proxies has this kind of functionality built in. Also take a look at

https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy

http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.304/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm.

If you are planning to build your own these can serve as a base.

Comment: You are correct. I would keep the anonymized URL and present to user on request. Once they click of the URL, I am expecting a third party public server (Amazon Nginx) to decode the URL and serve the request. Updated with example.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do here is somewhat similar to another question I've answered in the past, where for each request by the client, you effectively want to make two requests to two different upstreams under the hood (first one to an upstream capable of decoding the URL, second one to actually fetch said decoded URL), but, of course, only return one result.

https://serverfault.com/questions/202011/nginx-and-2-upstreams/485044#485044

As mentioned on serverfault, you could use [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) to process another request, after the first one is complete.  You could then use [`$upstream_http_`](http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_http_) to make the subsequent request based on the original one, for example, using [`$upstream_http_location`](https://serverfault.com/questions/423265/how-to-follow-http-redirects-inside-nginx).

You might also want to look into `X-Accel-Redirect` header, introduced in this context at [`proxy_ignore_headers`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ignore_headers).

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question. All I need to know is how would Nginx decode anonymized URL? Nginx got anonymized URL request. There has to be a way to decode it.

Comment: @java_dude, you're kidding, right?  how is it supposed to do that?  I guess you could use mapping with http://nginx.org/r/map, but your question is completely unclear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, and where the encoding/decoding is supposed to come from.

Comment: I am not :). I own both sides of the request i.e Nginx and Application Server code. Application server anonymized fixed URL using special code I wrote. I can write a reverse code that can decode anonymized URL to fixed URL on Amazon Nginx. The question is, how can I incorporate reverse logic (could execute some script on each reach request) on Nginx to perform decoding. It could be a `Perl` script or `PHP` script that gets executed on Nginx. Hope I am making sense :)

Comment: I can agree my question might not be making sense. Question should have been, Can I execute a script on Nginx for each request? I should be able to decode that URL being asked and then forward to S3 for fetching that resource.

Comment: that's exactly what my answer is.  you first execute your normal script, through `proxy_pass` or cgi or whatever, then do another `proxy_pass` through `error_page` to fetch the actual resource.

Comment: @java_dude, I don't understand what issue you're still having with this answer.  which part is still unclear to you?  your script should respond with a `Location` HTTP Header, then you make a subsequent request through `error_page` handler to fetch the required resource; this means that for each request by the client, two internal requests are made; are you having problems with making such internal requests?  but that would be another question!